# Can't import CSV to ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to import CSV file to ClickHouse table:
`INSERT INTO default.tags  FROM INFILE '/home/sergey/test/tags_202309081557.csv' FORMAT CSV;`
but got strange error:
`SQL Error [78] [07000]: Code: 78. DB::Exception: Query has infile and was send directly to server. (UNKNOWN_TYPE_OF_QUERY) (version 23.8.2.7 (official build)) , server ClickHouseNode [uri=http://localhost:8123/default, options={use_server_time_zone=false,use_time_zone=false}]@207775645`

Maybe smbd faced such problem?

Thanks

I tried many times with different options? but result was the same

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running this from? This is a clickhouse-client feature (also Java client supports i believe). Its not a server function and wont work over other clients.

Comment: Hmmm... thanks anyway, i tried such also with a python client with the same result

Answer (score 0):

`FROM INFILE` is for the clickhouse-client. If you're using Python, you can use the `insert_file` function. Check the docs here: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/python#file-inserts

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use this function; yes file became visible, but it doesn't process csv correctly and raises an error